# Navigate through a dropdown list using keyboard arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html

Using Vanilla JavaScript (not using any framework), how can I add keyboard navigation to a simple dropdown? By simple dropdown I mean a very basic dropdown such as:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
     <div>Test Dropdown</div>
     <ul>
         <li>A</li>
         <li>B</li>
         <li>C</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Alongside with JavaScript, is there any HTML5 solution for this problem (such that the web browser would understand automatically without having to add any ad-hoc logic)?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way, unless you use `tabindex`, but that's not what you looking for, here's a js implementation https://codepen.io/mehuldesign/pen/eYpbXMg

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: Thanks for the link. The JavaScript code is pretty simple. Now I have some ideas how to simplify it and make a generic solution.

Comment: When you say *keyboard navigation*, what keys are you targetting? If tab is included in them, you will have to consider adding a focus trap as well. "Hitting tab can take focus from dropdown as a popup to elements in the foreground elements. So on last element, on tab press, you will have to manually focus the first"(a.k.a Focus Trap)

Comment: @Rajesh: I clearly mentioned I meant arrow keys.

Comment: That's a list not a dropdown.... dropdowns use the `select` tag, they have keyboard navigation natively. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp

Comment: @ChrisHamilton: It's conceptually the skeleton for a dropdown

Comment: @ChrisHamilton: Built-in dropdowns have limited support for styling. That's why I don't usually use them.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder Sorry. Didn't read the title. Was going through description only.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder ah, so just a list then. Radios are good for that, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just `.focus()` on it then you can use your keyboard arrows.

```js
document.getElementById("dropdown").focus();
```

```html
 <label for="dropdown">Choose an option:</label>
 <select class="dropdown" name="dropdown" id="dropdown">

         <option>A</option>
         <option>B</option>
         <option>C</option>
     
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Radios will give you all the native functionality, you can hide the bubbles with `appearance: none` and put a label immediately after the input for styling.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

input[type=radio]+label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="A"/>
<label for="A">A</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="B"/>
<label for="B">B</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="C"/>
<label for="C">C</label>
```

`appearance` support: https://caniuse.com/?search=appearance

Note that the `for` property of the label being the same as the `id` of the input is what allows you to click the label to select the hidden radio.

---

You can put any html elements in the label tag to fully customize

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  display: block;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

input[type='radio'] + label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}

input[type='radio']:checked + label {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.a {
  width: min-content;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.b {
  width: min-content;
  color: blue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.c {
  width: min-content;
  color: green;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="A"/>
<label for="A"><div class="a">A</div></label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="B"/>
<label for="B"><div class="b">B</div></label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" id="C"/>
<label for="C"><div class="c">C</div></label>
```

Comment: This is indeed a smart trick! Because it doesn't make any sense to for a dropdown to have a multi-select behavior. However, the disadvantage of this approach is non-standard HTML markup.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder multi-select could always be added with JS, the radios are really just for navigation. Checkboxes may also work.